# How did I erase a branch from github history?

Tags: git, github

I actually didn't know how to ask this properly, I hope my question fits.

Here's what happened: I was basically working on a small project with git and so I created a new branch locally that I then pushed to my remote. Everything fine so far.

Today, as I was done with my branch, I merged it to master and then locally deleted it (`git branch -d branch_to_delete`) and then used git push to see the changes appear on github. Thing is, on github, the branch still existed and when I looked at the network, it looked like it never existed.

[image]

Weird right? So then I used `git push origin -d to_delete_branch` and the branch seemed to have been deleted on github but still it won't appear on the network... So my question is, what did I do wrong? x) Or actually, is anything wrong? Maybe it is supposed to look that way...

Comment: `but still it won't appear on the network.` - what do you mean?

Comment: as mentionned by matt, if you go see on my picture, there just a straight line rather than a railroad siding as I was expecting to see

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably because rather than merging Git did a "fast-forward".

Let's say you had this.

```
A - B [master]
     \
      C - D [feature]
```

Git branches are just labels pointing at a commit. Commits A and B are on master. And feature built C and D on top.

When you `git merge feature` Git notices that instead of merging it can simply move `master` to D. No merge necessary.

```
A - B
     \
      C - D [feature]
            [master]
```

The kink at B - C is artificial, so you see a linear history.

```
A - B - C - D [feature]
              [master]
```

This is a "fast forward". Git would have mentioned this when you did the `git merge.`

In contrast, let's say you did some work on master before merging.

```
A - B - E [master]
     \
      C - D [feature]
```

Because master and feature have "diverged" Git needs to merge the two code bases. `git merge feature` will produce a merge commit and the branch is retained in history.

```
A - B - E - F [master]
     \     /
      C - D [feature]
```

For this reason, use `git merge --no-ff` meaning "no fast-forward" to guarantee there is always a "feature bubble" even after the branch (really just the branch label) is deleted. Then just by looking at the history one knows that C and D were done as a logical group, and the merge commit message on F can provide context for why they were done.

Comment: okayyy! Thanks a lot for this detailed answer, guess I got my answer!

Answer (score 3):

A branch is just a *name*. That name exists, pointing to some commit or other, or it doesn't exist. In your case, it used to exist and now it doesn't, because you deleted it.

That has nothing at all to do with any *commits* that may or may not have been committed to that branch. Those commits are not lost, because you merged the branch into `master` before deleting its name, so you see them in the diagram.

If the question is why those commits appear in a straight line up to `master` rather than on a "railroad siding", it's probably because the merge to `master` was fast-forwarded.

Comment: okay I didn't see it that way! things are clearer now thanks. so, what is/are the other kind of possible merge?

Comment: Well, if a merge can't be fast-forwarded, it generates a new commit with two (usually) parents. That results in the "railroad siding" shown in blue on your diagram.